# Sql Timeout expired in Windows Forms application

Tags: sql-server, timeout

My windows forms application throws a Sql timeout expired exception every time I modify the code and build and run it. If I re-run it right after the exception, the connection works fine. Can anyone suggest what's causing the timeout?

Thanks.

Comment: May be its your query which is taking to much time.Run your query in sql server and see how much time it is taking.

Comment: It happens when I try to test if the connection is established successfully and displaying a message on the form. It happens with other simple winforms too. I don't think it's a problem with the query.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using sql server express? I had the same problem ... I remember "solving" it by changing the priority of the used protocols in the sql server configuration manager ... or by disabeling all protocols except one ... but I don't remember which one it was ... you have to try yourself ...

Comment: I fixed it by increasing the connection timeout.